# How to fix undefined index

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog

```
   //here are some of my declarations
        $sex   = @$_POST["sex"];
            $bdate = @$_POST["bdate"];
            $firstname = @$_POST["firstname"];
            $lastname  = @$_POST["lastname"];
            $profPic   = @$_FILES["prof-pic"];

        <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name">Profile Picture</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
```

**Notice**:  Undefined index: profPic in **C:\xampp\htdocs\slamB\profile.php** on line **152**
 />

```
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" value="<?=$user['profPic']?>"  disabled>

            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use isset like `$profPic   = isset($_FILES["prof-pic"])?$_FILES["prof-pic"]:'';`

Comment: Don't use the error suppression operator (@) as it hides error messages that may be helpful in debugging your code. You should also always write your code so it does not generate any PHP errors including notices.

Comment: Start by removing the `@`'s.

Comment: nothing happened